# Yield inside two functions

Tags: python, generator

I would like to access each generated object separately, without having the need to iterate directly over the generator function.

I have the following "generator" function which figures out whether I should download a file or return it as a file object

```py
def retrieve_file(content, to_download, filename):
    if to_download: 
        # Should download this file to the local computer
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(content)
        return filename
    else:
        # Do not download, keep it as a file object
        output = StringIO()
        output.write(content)
        return output # Should be replaced with yield?
```

The following function which actually downloads the files and calls the previous function

```
def get_all_files(to_download):
    for year in [2000, 2001, 20002, 2003]:
        content = download_file(year)
        result = retrieve_file(content,
                               to_download,
                               'file-%s.pdf' % year)
        return result
```

And the main function which in this case downloads all files as objects and then parses each one separately

```
def main():
    for file in get_all_files(True):
        parse_file(file)
```

In this example, having get_all_files function removed, and replacing the second return in retrieve_file with yield, would work. The problem is that I would like to separate the 2 functions (main and get_all_files) because they are in two different modules

Comment: Is that the entirety of `get_all_files`? What are you doing with `result`?

Comment: Until now I have not returned it because I used to call it with to_download=False. edited

Comment: FYI, the variable `to_download` in `retrieve_file` is confusing, because you aren't actually downloading anything in that function.

Comment: That's true, I will take that into account :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `return` in your `get_all_files` with `yield`. This will allow you to iterate over each file.

```
def get_all_files(to_download):
    for year in [2000, 2001, 20002, 2003]:
        content = download_file(year)
        result = retrieve_file(content,
                               to_download,
                               'file-%s.pdf' % year)
        yield result
```

Comment: How about the option if to_download=False?

Comment: Why would that matter? In both cases you return an object that is returned. It will behave the same way.